# why do we need to export a class in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I am a beginner, so, please bear with me, if this sounds too trivial.When i searched over the net for this, i got results showing how to do it. My question is why we do it in the first place ?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on what you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "export a class"?

Comment: why do we need to do __declspec(dllimport)/__declspec(dllexport) a class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is specific to the Windows platform, when you're developping C++ DLLs.

You have to use the __declspec(dllexport) modifier in order for your class and its methods to appear on the exported symbol list for your DLL.

This way, executables using your DLL can instanciate and call methods in these classes.

However you have to make sure that the executable and the DLL are compiled by the same version of the same compiler, because C++ symbols are exported using a relatively complex name mangling encoding (you can see that using [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)), which format varies from one compiler to another.

Comment: its not specific to Windows. Symbian OS uses exports with def files.

Comment: @Dynite: dllexport is specific to the Windows platform. I did not mention def files, since they're not really suited to export full class symbols, given the complexity of name mangling.

Comment: dllexport might be, but exporting isn't.

Comment: Can somebody explain me how this works ? According to my understanding, dll gets loaded at run time, and based on the objects (pertaining to that dll), the function gets called from the dll. So, if I have created an object(from dll) in my executable, then is it needed to still expose my dll functions ?

Comment: @Atul - If you want to call something that is not in your executable (i.e. its in a dll), then those functions must be exported so that your exe can find them (link)

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to export anything, unless you're creating a DLL. In that case, you can use the [dllexport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2%28VS.80%29.aspx) attribute as an alternative to the "old school" way of using [.def](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28VS.80%29.aspx) files.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you cannot export a class, only functions.
However you can designate on a class level that all functions be exported.

Exporting a function means that that function can be called from outside of the current executable.

This is needed when you are writing a dll for example which is a separate entity.

Comment: This is not correct. You can put the `__declspec(dllexport)` modifier on a class, which will take care of exporting all the class's function members with mangled names.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is correct, you can't export a class only functions. However you can specify that you want all the functions in a class exported by marking the class. The distinction is subtle I'll agree :)

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) is not C++, it's a vendor specific extension